# Animating scrolling/changing text from array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am looking for a way to make the changing text in a scrolling animation such as here :https://www.flexpool.io/
I made it change from an array, but need some help animating it :)

```js
var texts = new Array();
texts.push("One");
texts.push("Two");
texts.push("Three");
texts.push("etc");

var point = 0;

function changeText() {
  $('span').html(texts[point]);
  if (point < texts.length - 1) {
    point++;
  } else {
    point = 0;
  }
  setTimeout(changeText, 2100)
}

changeText();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span></span>
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for "jquery vertical carousel" here on Stackoverflow?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many. Here is one using the deprecated marquee, just because I could and to show you alternative syntax

```js
const texts = ["One","Two","Three","etc"];

let point = 0;

const changeText = () => {
  $('marquee').html(texts[point]);
  point++;
  if (point >= texts.length) point = 0;
}
setInterval(changeText, 2100)
changeText();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Hello
<marquee direction="down" width="50" height="20" scrolldelay="210">
```